# sql insert query through text file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert data from excel sheet to sql database. The query is stored in a text file as follows:

```
insert into [demo].[dbo].[relative] 
select *  
from openrowset('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database=D:\relative.xls','select * from [sheet1$]');
```

When I am executing the following command:

```
sqlcmd -S ADMIN-PC/SEXPRESS -i d:\demo.txt.
```

it is showing this error:

> Msg 7357, Level 16, State 2, Server ADMIN-PC\SEXPRESS, Line 1

Can anyone please help in rectifying my problem.

Comment: Are you using Excel or Text file?  OpenRowSet should be the method to do this.  You seem a bit confused on the Data Provider you need.

Comment: I want to add data from excel sheets and in demo.txt i've written a number of similar queries to add in different tables of the database.

Comment: Can you post the complete error message?

Comment: I have 20 excel files to be imported into 20 tables of sql database which i want to import in an automated manner. If i can implement that in any way. Apart from my solution as well.

Comment: @Aditi - great. now you mention that. Is this a one time job ? If yes, then use Import/Export wizard or DTS Wizard. Chenqui.

Comment: No its not a one time job. I need to update my database once in every 15 days.

Comment: @Aditi - Then you might have to learn SSIS. Make a package/code with SSIS, to first load the files and then only load the updates or deltas. Then learn how to schedule these packages to run every 15 days. Ideally, log all this in some kind of audit table. Thats how I'd do it. Chenqui.

Comment: Thanx I'll learn that and come to you if encounter any problem.

Comment: @Aditi - Its going to take a while to learn SSIS though. So, I suggest that you don't abandon your original approach right away. People prefer to use SSIS instead of several scattered batch files and what not.

Comment: Your error mentions `@sometable` but this isn't in your script. What aren't you telling us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the sql server import vizard to create a new table from the xls file and then insert that data to the existing table from there. The problem you are having is maybe due to the non-compatibility between 64bit sql instance and 32 bit excel.

Or try using `bcp`

```
bcp demo.dbo.relative in "D:\relative.xls" -c -T
```

Comment: I m on a project to develop a completely automated pipeline and i need to embed it into my pipeline. So i need some way to import it from command prompt and not through wizard.

Comment: Try `bcp demo.dbo.relative in "D:\relative.xls" -c -T`

Comment: Thanx, it successfully fulfilled my purpose.

Comment: Please do not accept answers when they do not function. You cannot import an Excel file through BCP.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to get the same result..

create a temp table.

```
declare @sometable table (value varchar(50), translation varchar(max))
select * into @sometable from YOUR_DATABASE_TABLE (nolock)
```

Then, do your OPENROWSET, BCP, etc. from here..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shell script which will automatically read the insert commands from the .csv file and then write it to the database. If you want I can help you up with it. What you just need to do is to write all the insert statements in the .csv file.

```
#!/bin/ksh
sqlplus -silent /nolog  << EOF > /dev/null
username/pwd@"Connection String"
set linesize 0;
set pagesize 0;
set echo off;
while read line; do
A=`echo "$line" | awk -F" " {print 1}`
and so on depends on the number of words in the insert statements.
$A $B  
done < your_insert_statements.csv
```

It will read the .csv file and automatically insert the records in the database.